# Firewall strips Preflight Option Response Header

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2, firewall

We have firewall configured on our network. So while accessing a Web API hosted outside the network, we are facing the problem. CORS is implemented over the server. Preflight Option Request is made, and server is setting the required response headers. But to the browser sitting behind this firewall in our network, doesn't get the headers.

If I try to access same API from outside the network, it works as expected.

Any pointers, where we can look into the firewall settings, to get around the problem.

Comment: We are running into the same issue, but it is about .3% of clients that are getting this issue. So, it looks like it is us, would be nice if we could provide a solution.